# How to store a "function call" result in a formControlName

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to store the result from the function in the formControlName but I am Receiving the error message below:

```
12main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'writeValue')
    at xe (main.js:1:4203086)
    at Oe.value (main.js:1:4234720)
    at Oe.value (main.js:1:4239942)
    at Oe.value (main.js:1:4239315)
    at Oe.Hs (main.js:1:4058639)
    at cn (main.js:1:4063595)
    at Zt (main.js:1:4063393)
    at rt (main.js:1:4063115)
    at r_ (main.js:1:4091203)
    at Object.y0 (main.js:1:4091050)
```

this is the html tags:

```
<div>
<button mat-fab
    color="primary" 
    disabled 
formControlName="TypeSelected"
>   
    {{selectedRequestType(requestForm.value)}}
</button>
</div>
```

this is the ts function
export class RequestBusComponent implements OnInit {
selectedRequestType(requestForm: any) {
if (
requestForm.goAddress != "" &&
requestForm.comeAddress == ""
) {
return "Outbound";
} else if (
requestForm.goAddress == "" &&
requestForm.comeAddress != ""
) {
return "Inbound";
} else if (
requestForm.goAddress != "" &&
requestForm.comeAddress != ""
) {
return "Both";
} else {
return "Your Request Selection Is Shown Here";
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Please share the form initialization code so that it is easier to help. But assuming the FormControlName of "TypeSelected" belong to the FormGroup of "requestForm", you may set the value to the formControl before returning.

```
selectedRequestType(requestBusArrayForm: any) {
        const val = "Your Request Selection Is Shown Here";

        if (
            requestForm.goAddress != "" &&
            requestForm.comeAddress == ""
        ) {
            val = "Outbound";
            requestForm.get("TypeSelected").setValue(val);
        } else if (
            requestForm.goAddress == "" &&
            requestForm.comeAddress != ""
        ) {
            val = "InBound";
            requestForm.get("TypeSelected").setValue(val);
        } else if (
            requestForm.goAddress != "" &&
            requestForm.comeAddress != ""
        ) {
            val = "Both";
            requestForm.get("TypeSelected").setValue(val);
        } 

        return val;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, TypeSelect does below to the FormGroup requestForm... I also try your recommendation however I am receiving the error.. "Get is not a function"

Comment: Could you please share the form initialization code to understand better